# Method String encode(String str) that encodes the contents of string str according to the following rules using switch statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am trying to write a method which encodes the contents of string
str according to the following rule: letters of str that appear in the word “cipher” should each be replaced by the following letter in that word (ie “c” becomes “i”, “i” becomes “p”, Letter “r” should become “c”,etc). T

I just get errors when trying to compile this code which says

> incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to String

and

> String.java:5: error: cannot find symbol System.out.println(a.length);.

```
public class NewString{

    public String encode(String str){
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            switch(str){
                case str.charAt(i) == "c":
                    str.replace("c", "i");
                    break;
                case str.charAt(i) == "i":
                    str.replace("i", "p");
                    break;
                case str.charAt(i) == "p":
                    str.replace("p", "h");
                    break;
                case str.charAt(i) == "h":
                    str.replace("h", "e");
                    break;
                case str.charAt(i) == "e":
                    str.replace("e", "r");
                    break;
                case str.charAt(i) == "r":
                    str.replace("r", "c");
                    break;
            }
        }

    return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NewString test = new NewString();
        String a = "cipher";

        System.out.println(test.encode(a));

    }
}
```

Comment: About the first error: Does one of your own classes happen to be named `String`? Then it will be picked up instead of the standard class `java.lang.String`. Give your class a different name, to make sure they don't get mixed up.

Comment: Your approach will not work, even using current answers, because `String` is an immutable class in Java. `String.replace` is returning a new string with the replaced char, but you are ignoring it. You are returning the same String object you are using as parameter to your method.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's `str.length()`, not `str.length`. `String` has a method `length()`, not a field `length`.
2. It's `str.charAt(i) == 'c'`, not `str.charAt(i) == "c"`. Both operands must be `char`s to use `==`. `"c"` is a `String` literal. `'c'` is a `char` literal.
3. You probably meant

   ```
   char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
   switch(currentChar) {
        case 'c':
            ...
            break;
   }
   ```
4. `str.replace("i", "p");` makes no impact on `str`, you need to read a result. `str = str.replace("i", "p");` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the switch construct here a bit. Have a look at the sample below:

```
String newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
  switch(str.charAt(i)){
    case 'c':
      newStr = newStr + "i";
      break;
    ...
    default:
      newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);
  }
}
```

In the switch you want to specify the argument you want to compare with. In this case you want to check the character at a given index. In the case branches you want to specify the value you want to compare with, in this case your letters. Note that these are characters, which are defined between single quotes instead of double quotes.

Then there are still other issues with your logic, if your string for example is "ccc", the first iteration will create "iii", the next iteration will create "ppp", and so on... An option would be to create a new String I suppose and store the converted characters that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach has some issues.

- The `replace` method returns a `String` that you are ignoring.
- After the `case` you can only use constants, but are using a function. This function should be moved to the `switch` section.
- The `String::replace` is alway replacing all the occurrences in the string, not the occurrence in your index. So the result is not the expected neither.
- What happens when your word changes? You'll need to rewrite the entire method. I know that you are describing a specific case, but in a real world you want your code is open to extensions.

Taking advantage of your requirement I have reworked your code so:
`Given a text and a encoding word`
`When a character of the word is found in the text`
`Then this character is replaced with the next character in the word, or the first if the this was the last character.`

Check this implementation:

```
public class StringEncoder {

    public static String encode(String stringToEncode, String encodingWord) {
        return stringToEncode.chars()
                .map(character -> getEncodedChar(encodingWord, (char) character))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                        StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();

    }

    private static char getEncodedChar(String word, char character) {
        int i = word.indexOf(character);
        boolean characterInWord = i >= 0;
        if (characterInWord) {
            return nextChar(word, i);
        } else {
            return character;
        }
    }

    private static char nextChar(String word, int i) {
        return word.charAt((i + 1) % word.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(encode("cipher", "cipher"));
        System.out.println(encode("A text with cipher word", "cipher"));
        System.out.println(encode("love", "love"));
        System.out.println(encode("A text with love word", "love"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on comments and other answers a simple approach similar to your code.

```
public class NewString {
    public String encode(String str){
        StringBuilder encodedString=new StringBuilder(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char charToConvert=str.charAt(i);
            switch(charToConvert){
                case 'c':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1,"i");
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1, "p");
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1, "h");
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1, "e");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1, "r");
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    encodedString.replace(i,i+1, "c");
                    break;
            }
        }

        return encodedString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NewString test = new NewString();
        String a = "cipher";

        System.out.println(test.encode(a));

    }
}
```